# Add on to Make Categories 'Required' in Channel Form?

Tags: categories, safecracker

Is there a way to make category checkboxes work like custom fields and be 'required' in Channel Form? With a message that shows the error if not?

Been looking for a plugin but doesn't seem like there is one..

Anyone had to do something like this?

Comment: If you are simply trying to have a "default" category selected then you can set that up in the channel preferences.

Comment: Thanks Foamcow - basically there were two sections of a long form (Business Type and Main Area) which were required checkbox fields but for some unrelated reason we needed to change these to categories instead of custom fields so yes, it would be required to choose at least one of each - it doesn't actually matter which one, the main purpose is to avoid them not filling it in.

So in the Channel Prefs could we apply this to the two category groups? And what about the message if they leave unfilled? Is that possible do you know?

Answer (score 2):

I often use [BW Required Category](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bw-required-category) with great success - does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I saw it but I wasn't sure it could give an error message or be compatible with Channel Form... do you know if it can give an error?

Comment: It does provide an error message, yes, though I can't say whether it will do so with Channel Forms.

Comment: Hey Derek, since you are using the plugin, does it still work for you with 292 ? Having some problems myself. https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26291/update-to-ee-2-9-2-and-bw-required-category-stopped-working

Comment: Haven't upgraded any sites using it to 2.9.2 yet I'm afraid.