# Update to EE 2.9.2 and BW Required Category stopped working

Tags: add-on, upgrade

After upgrading a site to 2.9.2 (from 2.9.0) it looks like BW required category stopped working.

1. Is anybody else experiencing this? Can anybody reproduce ? (the add-on is widely used I believe) I get a 'You are not authorized to access this page' error
2. From what I can see, it looks like it returns an `entry_id=0` in the URL, which results in an error.

I disabled the quicksave extension and that's the URL I get:
`/cp/content_publish/view_entry&channel_id=1&entry_id=0&S=89068fcf88fe6b9aa32a5f76ed2284f4`

before EE 292 upgrade I had this:
`/cp/content_publish/entry_form&channel_id=1&S=dae16113bd4f7c4803125dc2ed732045`

Is there a way to fix this ?

I contacted the dev via twitter but he says he's not updating his add-ons anymore. Must be something relatively simple to fix but cannot figure it out.

Comment: I'd love to have it working too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: ended up disabling BW required category